# Does this tomato plant look alright?

Tags: indoors, tomatoes

I started growing tomatoes inside my apartment. All over the internet, I noticed pictures of tomato plants that are really thick with lots of leaves and branches. Mine is tall, thin and has only a few branches. Maybe I'm a little paranoid, but does my plant look alright?

In the pictures, the plant is ~35 days old, the pot is 12 inches and the plant is about 15 inch tall.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Looks fine for a tomato plant indoors.  Is there anyway you can get that guy outside?  They grow well in pots, you'd be able to get a few yummy tomatoes but they need a heck of a lot more light.  Is that a grow light? Not strong enough, though.  It is long and leggy because it is searching for more light.

Comment: Agreed - you won't get much, if any, fruit on a tomato plant that is not getting nearly full sun.